# Filter toolbar not coming in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using free jqGrid 4.14. I am having trouble in displaying filter toolbar in the grid. I am using the same code that I was using to display filter toolbar in version 4.1.2
but here the toolbar is not appearing.

I need the toolbar to display only when filter image is clicked in the grid otherwise it should hide. So, I am using the below code for that in previous version but here in new the same is 
not working

```
 grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "jsonstring",
        datastr: grid_data,
        colNames: scopes.grid_header_column_value,
        colModel: scopes.gridcolumns,
        height: height,
        viewrecords: is_pager_enable,
        multiSort: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        grouping: is_group_enable,
        sortorder: sort_order,

        sortable: false,
        pager: "#" + pager_id,
        treeGrid: true,
        treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
        treedatatype: "local",
        ExpandColumn: 'name',         

        gridComplete: function () {

            $("#" + grid_id+"count").html($("#" + grid_id).getGridParam('records')+" row(s)");

        },
         beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
          var item = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);
             if (item != null && item.isLeaf) {
             $("#"+$rootScope.subpopup).css("display", "block");
             $scope.getPopup($rootScope.xmlname,grid_id,rowid);

                       } 
          return true;   // allow row selection
        },
        loadComplete: function () {
            var ts = this;
            //document.querySelector('#filterbutton').addEventListener('onclick', clickqw);
            if (ts.p.reccount === 0) {
                $(this).hide();
                emptyMsgDiv.show();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                emptyMsgDiv.hide();
            }

        }            
    });


grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn", searchOperators: true }).navGrid("#" + pager_id, { edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: true, search: false });
```

Here I am hiding or showing the bar on need basis

```
var count = 1;
        grid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view").find("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv table.ui-jqgrid-htable tr.ui-jqgrid-labels > th.ui-th-column > div.ui-jqgrid-sortable > button.btnfilter ")
                .each(function () {
                    $('<button>').css({ height: '10px',background: 'url(img/filter.png) no-repeat',border: '0'
                        }).appendTo(this).button({
                        icons: {
                            primary: ""
                        },
                        text: false
                        }).click(function (e) {

                        var idPrefix = "jqgh_" + grid[0].id + "_",
                            thId = $(e.target).closest('div.ui-jqgrid-sortable')[0].id;                      
                        if (thId.substr(0, idPrefix.length) === idPrefix) {
                            if (count == 1) {
                                $('#gview_' + grid_id).find("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv table.ui-jqgrid-htable tr.ui-search-toolbar").show();
                                count = 0;
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#gview_' + grid_id).find("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv table.ui-jqgrid-htable tr.ui-search-toolbar").hide();
                                count = 1;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                });

       $('#gview_' + grid_id).find("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv table.ui-jqgrid-htable tr.ui-search-toolbar").hide();
```

EDIT : Adding the images

This is when image where there the filter is not applied. Only the image (funnel image) for filter where the filter can be applied is shown.

[image]

Here when we click on the image of filter only then the filtertoolbar should appear.

[image]

Comment: The picture, which shows what you try to implement, and **the demo** would be helpful. It's unclear *where* (in which callback) you use the code. The above code suppose very exact names and the order of all elements in the filter toolbar. Moreover you make assumptions about the ids of internal elements of jqGrid. It was a lot of changes in the last years (between 4.1.2 and 4.14.0). The internal structure of the filter toolbar is changes because of support of new options.

Comment: @Oleg I have added the images as well as the position where I am applying the code. the code which has property to hide and show filter toolbar is applied just after that.

Comment: I have to do other things now from my main job. I will read your changes later...

Comment: @Oleg ok sir whenever you are free

Comment: I'm not sure that I correctly understand what you do because you don't provide the corresponding demo, but it seems to me that the solution could be very simple. see https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/curhufz8/ which has the base functionality.

Comment: Actually I was following your solution only that I got it from here...https://relaxbuddy.com/forum/thread/22772/add-button-to-jqgrid-column-header... .but not able to apply filter for a particular column...I have added a button name with class to that column where filter is applied but still it is not finding..yet I can see the button in DOM elements

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/curhufz8/1/.